# Change or edit image file name in phonegap

Tags: cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to change or give a custom image file name instead of the default image name in camera API cordova? [For both IOS and android] Version Cordova 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
var captureSuccess = function (mediaFiles) {
   // SystemURI require string and path2 will deal it and must not use file:/(path)
   var path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
   var path2 = path.slice(0, 5) + "//" + path.slice(5);
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path2, successMoveTo, fail);
}

function successMoveTo(entry) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (fileSys) {
           fileSys.root.getDirectory(folder, {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function (directory) {
                entry.moveTo(directory, file,
                    success, fail);
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
}
```